# How to put a func () inside another function in swift sprite kit?

Tags: xcode, function, swift

I need to put a function without anything inside the () in another function.
I have this done but it doesn't run because I need to add something inside the parenthesis().
sorry for my english.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var color = UIColor(red: 50, green: 100, blue: 150, alpha: 1)

    func spawnColumn () {

        var g1 = SKSpriteNode(color: color, size: CGSizeMake(20, 300))

        g1.position = CGPoint(x: xposG1, y: 235)

        addChild(g1)

    }

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    func spawnColumnEveryTwoSeconds() {

        let spawnAction = SKAction.runBlock(spawnColumn) HERE IS THE ERROR

    }


    let waitTwoSeconds = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)

    let spawnAndWait = SKAction.sequence([spawnAction,waitTwoSeconds])

    let spawnAndWaitForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnAndWait)

    self.runAction(spawnAndWaitForever)

}

}
```

Comment: What error do you get and what is the signature of SKAction.runBlock()?

Comment: that i canot runblock with a function without something inside the ()

Comment: Is it compile time error or run time error?